# Find Newly Deployed Smart Contracts on Ethereum Mainnet

Tags: python, ethereum, blockchain, web3py, erc20

I am attempting to write a python script with web3.py that will be continuously run to look for deployments of ERC20 smart contracts. I believe the first step would be to look for newly deployed smart contracts.

How would I be able to look at the most recent transactions and look for newly deployed ERC20 smart contracts?

```
from web3 import Web3

print("hello world")
provider_url = 'https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/c4c4fa6e6baf4d02b165d0a0ee4d2485'
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(provider_url))
print(w3.is_connected())
count = 0

while True:
    latest_block = dict(w3.eth.get_block('latest'))

    for transaction in latest_block["transactions"]:
        tx = w3.eth.get_transaction_receipt(transaction)
        print(tx)
        if not tx["to"]:
            count += 1
    print(count)
```

This is what I have tried so far. I am looking into the latest block, and then iterating through the list of transactions and checking if there is a "to" address. However, I realized this may not work as there may still be a "to" address on smart contract deployment.

How would I be able to differentiate a smart contract deployment transaction from a regular transaction?

After this, how would I differentiate an ERC20 smart contract with any other type of contract?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

1. Use eth.get_code to see if there is byte code deployed at the address. I use this to test if an address is a Contract or EOA.
2. ERC20 compliant contracts have a standard set of functions such as name, decimals, balanceOf, totalSupply, etc. You can call these on the contract address to see if you get back a ContractLogicError or a response that seems reasonable.